# How to avoid the Google Webmaster Tools API limit

Tags: api, web-crawler, limit, google-search-console

I just wrote an application which gets the crawl issues of Google Webmaster Tools. The API has a limit of 100 entries per request. Is there any solution or workaround to get all crawl issues in one time?

Answer (score 0):

Google Api Query bottleneck issue generally can be resolved by controlling each or (batch) query thread(s) via static / dynamic your internal thread-running rate (i.e., java concurrency with threadpool/buffer). In short, you would want to have your own query thread controller.